# How to set an Id for Iframe in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have an HTML page to be displayed in `iframe` in `ExtJS`. I want to set an `id` for that specific `iframe`, how can I do that?

Please refer the sample code below, I have assigned a `sampleId` but it doesn't work at all.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'Open other html file inside of window',
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: "component",
                autoEl: {
                    id: "sampleId",
                    tag: "iframe",
                    src: "res/example.html"
                }
            }]
        }).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the setting of the `id` onto the component itself:

```
items: [{
    xtype: "component",
    id: 'sampleId',
    autoEl: {
        tag: "iframe",
        src: "res/example.html"
    }
}]
```

Comment: This worked for this code, the iframe has an id now. Thanks.

Comment: this.add( new Ext.Component({                   
   id:'sampleID',
   autoEl: {                        
    tag: 'iframe',                         
    src: this.encodeUrl(url,params)                  
   }});

How would you add id while dynamically adding a component?

Comment: The same way you would use any other variable.